# Problems with ThisWorkbook when using Excel Add In

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following lines of code that essentially copy and paste a sheet from one workbook into another:

```
Dim wb As Workbook, CopyFromWbk As Workbook, CopyToWbk As Workbook
Dim ShToCopy As Worksheet, targetSheet As Worksheet, sht As Worksheet
Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult

Answer = MsgBox("OPEN", vbOKCancel, "OPEN")
If Answer = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
Set wb = FileDialog_Open()
If wb Is Nothing Then End

Call Sheet_Selector

Set CopyFromWbk = wb
Set ShToCopy = CopyFromWbk.ActiveSheet
Set CopyToWbk = ThisWorkbook
ShToCopy.Cells.Copy
Set targetSheet = 
CopyToWbk.Sheets.Add(After:=CopyToWbk.Sheets(CopyToWbk.Sheets.Count))
targetSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, 
Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
targetSheet.Name = "Sheet2"
CopyFromWbk.Close False
```

The problem is that when you use an Excel Add-In you have to be careful about using ThisWorkbook as it is actually addressing the Add In and not my workbook. I can't use "ActiveWorkbook" as it addresses the workbook I am copying from not copying to.

So I am struggling to figure out how to fix this. Note this code works perfectly when not used in the Excel Add In (due to the fact that I am using ThisWorkbook).

EDIT: All I had to do was move `Set CopyToWbk = ActiveWorkbook` to the top of the code and it worked of course.

Comment: `Set CopyFromWbk = wb` at the point this runs, `wb` is Nothing (has not been set to anything)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the first part of the code - fixed. The code works perfectly if I don't use it in an Excel Add In. This is due to me using ThisWorkbook.

Comment: As a human, how would you decide which is your target workbook?  (e.g. do you know its file name?  Do you know that it is the only other workbook that is open other than the source workbook and the add-in workbook?  Some other way?)  If you can tell us that, we can work out how to get your code to emulate what you would do personally.